# Export SMF posts into Drupal forum

Tags: drupal, export, smf

I am currently working on a Drupal 6 site and would love it if there's a way I could import everything over from an already existing SMF site.

By everything I actually mean :

- users and their passwords
- their postings
- the forum structure (i.e sub boards and such)

I have the Drupal site set up on a developmental server so I can experiment with it. The SMF site however is a production site.

Thanks in advance for any help from you wonderful people.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to port everything to Drupal?  Could you get away with just integrating it, as in using [this module](http://drupal.org/project/smfforum)?  Get the theming sorted and most people won't recognise they're switching between applications, you won't get the profiles linked perfectly but you'll get some pretty good integration.

If you do want to import all the data then I expect it'll be rather difficult, and you'll be hanging out in the Drupal irc channels asking a lot of questions about the forum module and APIs.  http://api.drupal.org/ will become an oft-visited site.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I do not want ALL the data, just the forum posts and the users.

Comment: I'm confused, what else does a forum have that isn't forums, posts and users?